# Angular.js // ng-leave state before url/ng-view change

Tags: angularjs, browser-history, ng-animate

Getting into **ngAnimations**; I was wondering how page transition could completely be controlled.

I mean by this : being able to control the same way an ng-leave as it is done for the ng-enter while **having a change in the url in the process**. New to angular but I'd described it as trying to get some ng-leave control before an ng-view change.

As far as I've searched, the ng-leave state only has a meaning with [ng-switch](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation) (there is another ng but you got the idea); which for the moment means for me that all the elements have to be already in the page and that no url change are involved in the process.

If any help, highly appreciated. I've found the ng-animations really cool but thinking that this point is quite missing.

Assuming there might be another pattern to follow probably though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read:

**Animation in AngularJS**
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html

**Enhanced Animation in AngularJS**
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/05/enhanced-animations-in-angularjs.html

**Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2**
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

I have found these useful.

Comment: Ended up on this; I guess not enough
thanks for pointing; I'll come back later